# How do you change the owner of a database in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In management studio you can see the owner under properties but it won't let you change it. My guess is there's some stored procedure to change it and you can't do it through the gui.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Surpisingly, it's called [`sp_changedbowner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178630.aspx).

You can actually change it in `SQL Server Management Studio` under `Database / Properties / Files`

Answer (score 32):

In addition to using `SSMS` GUI, you can also use `ALTER AUTHORIZATION` or alternately use `sp_changedbowner` statement.

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::MyDatabaseName TO NewOwner;
GO
```

Please note `sp_changedbowner` is deprecated from `SQL Server 2012`.

Comment: I saw that method online (and your onliner worked, +1 for that). Any insight why there are two different ways?

Comment: `ALTER AUTHORIZATION` is a `DCL` in `T-SQL` that is used to alter authorization of database objects that have owners associated. `sp_changedbowner` is a Microsoft's implementation of the same function as a System Stored Procedure. In fact, `sp_changedbowner` is deprecated from SQL Server 2012, and using it is not a best practice anymore. Please refer Microsoft's documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178630.aspx.

Comment: This should be the answer considering the deprecation!

Answer (score 11):

Actually you can change it in SSMS, it's in the Files tab on the database properties.